# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `students`)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

[image]

I'm trying to make a CRUD app on laravel. server is on docker and localhost is on **0.0.0.0**

[image]

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `students`)

Comment: Did you run the migrations? Are you using docker? You need to add more info about your local stack, as there seems to be that it cannot communicate with MySQL or you did not run the migrations...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the model that you are try to calling. Check if you have created the Student model in app folder of your project.

if it is not there follow the guide to create and calling model through:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

change
From

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

To

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```